Tailwindcss is not reading all the files in a specified directory
I am using tailwind css with expo and tailwind is working perfectly fine for the old files but it is not applying to any new component that I add to my project within the same directory.
Here is my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./navigation/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

I have added a component "Home.js" to the "./screens/" directory but the styles are not working in there but they are working perfectly fine for other old components.

If your Home.js file is not into a screen  subfolder then "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", will not match it , as it is matching any file that in screens subfolders
You need "./screens/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",

BDurand's comment is incorrect. **/ will match 0 or more directories, so "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}" should match ./screens/Home.js just fine.
